# Full html code with all tags is not coming from site

Tags: python, html

I have written a Python WebScraper like this:

```
import urllib2,cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm?cat=G&utm_campaign=website&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
       }
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()

content = page.read()
print content
```

Now in this url there is a table which i need to scrape but whenevr i try to run this code the returned html has lots of `<tr>` and `<td>` tags missing. How can i get the full html printed?

Comment: Is this "missing" markup added to the target page by JavaScript? Sounds likely. It would be very strange for any web scraper to selectively change the incoming document, without specific instruction

Comment: The table is loaded by a Javascript module after the main page is loaded. You won't be able to scrape the data this way. You should look for an API. The site owners probably have one but it's likely to be chargeable.

Comment: If the data you're looking for is loaded by JavaScript, the data would either be from an AJAX call or would exist elsewhere on the page.  Check the network activity in your browser debugger for an AJAX call.  If there is one, *that's* what you want to "scrape" (which may end up being a lot easier if it's structured JSON data).  If there's no AJAX call, examine the loaded page for data in the JavaScript code or otherwise elsewhere hidden on the page.

Comment: Is there any other way without using an API??? can i use Selenium??

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors.. u can use scrapy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your question is actually "how do I get the data from the table?" not "how do I get the HTML as I view it in a web browser", the solution is, as pointed out in the comments, to look at where the content you want is coming from using Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
import requests                                                                 
import json                                                                     

r = requests.get("http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/"
                 "live_analysis/gainers/niftyGainers1.json")
data_as_json = json.loads(r.content)

for stock_info in data_as_json['data']:                   
    for key, value in stock_info.items():                                       
        print key, value
```

(I prefer using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) over urllib2 for working with HTTP.)